# How to plot select Y values in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to create a plot in Seaborn of cancer rates over time. My issue is that I only want to plot select y-axis values for this report. For example, looking at cancer rates by county per year, I would like to be able to graph only a few select counties instead of all. Below is the code I am using, which is returning all county results (y) as expected. How can I modify this to ONLY show certain ones (ex: Los Angeles, Yolo, Alameda, etc.)?

```
sns.relplot(x='Year',y = 'cancer/100k pop' , data = dataset_all,hue="County", kind="line",ci=None)
title_string = "Trend of " 
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.title(title_string)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can take a look, but I would need to see a sample of your dataset, and how you are reading it in.

Comment: use `hue_order`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that dataset_all is a pandas dataframe, the easiest solution is to filter the data.

For example,

```
display_counties = ['Los Angeles', 'Yolo', 'Alameda']
subset = dataset_all.loc[dataset_all['County'].isin(display_counties), :]
sns.relplot(x='Year',y='cancer/100k pop', data=subset, hue="County", kind="line",ci=None)
title_string = "Trend of " 
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.title(title_string)
```

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you!